# Генератор числа от 0 до 9999 на Js

Tags: javascript

Короче, нужен скрипт который будет будет выводить в input число которое начинается от 0001 затем
нажатие кнопки

```
a=document.getElementsByClassName("класс кнопки");
// Сама функция клика
function godsmack(){a[0].click();}
// Установка лимита интервала функции
setInterval(godsmack,time*1000);
```

дальше скрипт должен добавить к 0001 + 1 цифру(0002) и так по кругу
Есть кто подскажет как это провернуть?

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("класс кнопки");
function clicker() { 
  var event = new Event('click');
  a[0].dispatchEvent(event); 
}

var counter = 1;
var timer = setInterval(function(){
  if (counter < 9999) {
    document.getElementById("input id").value = counter++;
    clicker();
  } else {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 1000);
```